# How can you use nested for loops to print out the following pattern in python?

Tags: python

How do you use nested for loops to print out the following pattern? So you don't have to write 10 for loops for it.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20

3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30

4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40

5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50

6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60

7 14 21 28 35 42 49 54 63 70

8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 80

9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90

10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

Comment: Did my answer help you? If you need more help we can take this into a chat

Comment: Yeah, but I still don't understand how the multiplying part works. For the first iteration: print((0 + 1) * (0 + 1), end=" ") prints out 1 to 10. But the second iteration: print((1 + 1) * (1 + 1, end=" ") ??

Comment: Close! The first part will be `print((0+1) * (0+1))` = 1, then ONLY count increases, stepSize remains the same because we still haven't finished the inner for loop, so the next number is `print((1 + 1) * (0 + 1))` = 2. Then `print((2+1) * (0+1))` = 3, and so on...

Finally we reach `print((9+1) * (0+1)` = 10 and then we finish the first iteration of 10 in our **stepSize** loop. Then we start the next iteration except this time **stepSize** is one larger. e.g. `print((0+1) * (1+1))` = 2, and then `print((1+1) * (1+1))` = 4, and then `print((2+1) * (1+1))` = 6. See how that works?

Comment: I see how it works now, thanks!

Comment: Great! Don’t forget to upvote/accept my answer if you liked it to help other people searching for the same thing in the future!

Answer (score 2):

Simply increase your step size!

```
for stepSize in range(10):
    for count in range(10):
        print((count + 1) * (stepSize + 1), end=" ")
    # count loop has ended, back into the scope of stepSize loop
    # We are also printing(" ") to end the line
    print(" ")
# stepSize loop has finished, code is done
```

Explanation:
The first, outer loop is increasing our step size, then for each step size we count up 10 steps and finish the line when we `print(" ")` in the outer for loop.

Comment: The `+ 1`s here are used because the for loops will start at 0, and it seems you don't want that.

Comment: you should  add `end` parameter in 1st print statement. `print((i + 1) * (stepsize + 1), end=" ")`

Comment: I don't know how to interpret your codes. I understand that for stepsize in range(10): allows you to print from 0 to 9. I don't understand what does for i in range(10): mean inside the for loop above it. And why is the formula for the output equal to (i + 1) * (stepsize + 1)?

Comment: @YolandaHui I'll break it down line by line. Also, I changed the variable names to be more clear. The first line is a simple `for` loop counting from 0-9 and if we add `+1` to it we get 1-10 which is the desired step size (you want to increment first by 1, then 2, then 3, etc.). The second `for` loop will run from 0-9 again and again we need to add `+1` to it since you want to count from 1-10, not 0-9. This second loop here will run once for every step size (since it's inside of the `stepSize` for loop).

Comment: @YolandaHui Finally, within this inner loop we're multiplying the `stepSize` by the `count` to get your list. e.g. `1, 2, 3, ..., 10` and then the next `stepSize` iteration of the for loop gives `2,4,6, ..., 20` and so on. The `end=" "` simply says that the line will finish when a `print(" ")` is given, which we do at the end of `stepSize` loop

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
 for x in range (1,11):
    product = []
    for y in range (1, 11):
        current_product = x * y
        product.append(current_product)
    print(*product, sep=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be one of the least interpretable answers, but I had fun trying to write a one-liner:

```
num_rows = 10
print '\n\n'.join(' '.join(str(i) for i in range(j,(num_rows+1)*j)[::j]) for j in range(1,num_rows+1))
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20

3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30

4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40

5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50

6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60

7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70

8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 80

9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90

10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

Disecting it, `range(j,(num_rows+1)*j)[::j]` generates the integers for each line where `j` is ranging over the row number (starting with an index of 1 as you ask for). The `[::j]` part gives you every `j`-th element of the list. Then the inner join statement is constructing the line string from the list of integers, each integer separated by a space `' '`. The outer join constructs the final output by combining the lines of integers with `\n\n`, which is a double new line to put a blank line in between each line of integers.

I think the other solutions are more readable, but this one is kind of fun.